# simple terrain mesh into vectors for illustrator

Tags: mesh, vector, lines

[image]Im new to Blender (3D all together) and im looking to create a simple terrain mesh (as depicted in attached image) that i can export as vector lines to Adobe Illustrator and manipulate into an art print.

Any tips, guides or links to tutorials are more would be greatly appreciated.

Loving Blender but its a steep learning curve

Thank you (sending positive karma to anyone that can help)[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a plane, subdivide, create some bumps, select a ring of edges, extend the selection, with *Select > Select Loops > Edge Loops*, duplicate the selection and separate with <kbd>P</kbd>:

[image]

Convert to curve:

[image]

Do the same with the perpendicular edge loops (you could also have selected all the faces of the plane and removed the faces only but the curves would not be perpendicular afterwards, I don't know if it's important), join the 2 curve objects into one, rotate the object with double <kbd>R</kbd> until you have the wanted perspective:

[image]

in *Edit* mode scale it 0 on Z, export the object as svg, import it in your vectorial app:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply Moonboots,
Ive been working on it but like I said its a steep learning curve, Ill post the results

Comment: Hi,
so ive managed to create a subdevided plane (large) sculpted some bumps and selected the edge loops. But now im unsure on how to proceed with the DUPLICATE SELECTION and SEPERATE WITH P ? I have a screenshot added on top

Comment: Shift D to duplicate but instead you could select all and X > Only Faces